# Angular 2 ng2-redux and ngrx/store

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in Angular2, I know flux architecture and ng2 redux, ngrx/store but still confused which library is used for development of an application. Both of are provided the implementation of flux.
What is the difference between ng2-redux and ngrx/store?
What should be used in development?

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand, the primary difference between the two is that ng2-redux uses Angular bindings for existing React/Redux implementation, whereas ngrx/store is an entire reimplementation of Redux concepts. As a result, some people will argue that ng2-redux has better compatibility with React/Redux libraries, middleware, and devtools.

hendrikswan on Github, who made a pretty good Pluralsight course on Angular with Redux, also claims that ng2-redux is a "more optimized way" to introduce Redux to an existing Angular application. ([Source](https://github.com/hendrikswan/pluralsight-angular-redux/issues/2))

Despite all that, if you look and the [ng2-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) Github vs the [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md), looks like ngrx/store is a bit more popular. :)

Both are valid solutions to store management, so really it might just boil down to preference.